# How to exclude connected characters using Javascript RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

At below codes, I wanna get **fnc(abcdx);** and **fnc(abcdy);** as result using javascript regexp.

I have to exclude words ending with **xy**.

In this code, it should be `fnc(abcxy);`

```
var str = 'fnc(abcdx);fnc(abcxy);fnc(abcdy);';
```

So I tried this code, but it failed.

```
var rst = str.match(/fnc\([^xy]*\);/gi);
```

I know **[^xy]** excludes **x** or **y** not **xy**.

How can I make this to exclude continuous characters(**xy**) as like a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a negative lookahead to assert that what comes after the opening parenthesis and before the close parenthesis does not contain `xy`

```
\bfnc\((?![^()]*xy[^()]*\))[^()]*\);
```

**Explanation**

- `\bfnc` Word boundary, then match fnc
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, check what follows is not

  - `[^()]*xy[^()]*\)` Match `xy` between any char except parenthesis and match `)`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^()]*` Match 0+ times any char other than `(` or `)`
- `\);` Match `);`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hr9a0W/1)

```js
let str = 'fnc(abcdx);fnc(abcxy);fnc(abcdy);';
const pattern = /\bfnc\((?![^()]*xy[^()]*\))[^()]*\);/g;
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negative look behind `(?<!xy)` which matches anything that doesn't end in `xy`.

```js
let str = 'fnc(abcdx);fnc(abcxy);fnc(abcdy);';
let result = str.match(/fnc\([^)]*(?<!xy)\);/gi);
console.log(result);
```